# Evaluating $\int_C \frac{1}{(z+i)^2\cos z}\,\mathrm dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I need to calculate the following integral

$$\int_{|z| = 4} \frac{1}{(z+i)^2\cos z}\,\mathrm dz$$

I would imagine you are suppose to use the residue theorem in this problem. I know that the integrand has singularities at $z = -i, \pi/2, -\pi/2$. The residues at $-i$ is pretty easy to calculate because $\cos(z)$ is analytic at $z = -i.$ However, I was wondering how to calculate the residue at the other two points.

I realize that one way is to find the laurent expansion of the integrand at these points. I am getting that the residues at $z = \pm \pi/2$and is $0$ (I am not sure I am doing this correctly though). Thus, the integral would $2\pi i \tan^2(i)$. However, this seems like a strange answer to me. I am particularly concerned that I have calculated the residues at $z = \pm \pi/2$ incorrectly. Is there a simple way to calculate this integral that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poles at $\pm\pi/2$ are simple, so you can compute them as
$$
\text{Res}(f,c)=\lim_{z\to c}f(z)(z-c)
$$
where $c=\pm \pi/2$. To find the limit of $\frac{z-c}{\cos(z)}$ when $z\to c$, note that this will be $1$ over the derivative of $\cos$ at $c$.

Comment: How do you know the pole is simple?

Comment: Because $\cos$ has simple zeros at $\pm \pi/2$.

Comment: Yes! What about the $(z+i)^2$ wouldn't I have take into account this factor when I take the derivative?

Comment: In general, $\alpha$ is a zero of order $n$ of $f$ if and only if $\alpha$ is a pole of order $n$ of $\frac{1}{f}$. Holomorphic functions are sort of like polynomials, so meromorphic functions are sort of like rational functions.

Comment: @Mike Sorry, I didn't see your other question in time. When looking at $\lim_{z\to c} \frac{1}{(z+i)^2}\frac{z-c}{\cos(z)}$, the left quotient is not undertermined (for $c=\pm \pi/2$), so you just plug in $z=c$.

Comment: Okay, so the residue should be $\lim_{z \to c} \frac{1}{(z+i)^2} \frac{z-c}{\cos(z)}$, right ($c = \pm \pi/2$)?

Comment: Yes. I wrote only part of the limit in my answer because that's the tricky one, sorry if that was confusing :)

Comment: All Good! Thanks for the help!